# what is the "core" of symfony2?

Tags: symfony

the core *seems to be* everything beneath /vendor/symfony/src/Symfony.

There you have three folders:

- /Bridge
- /Bundle
- /Component

What is the purpose of /Bridge and /Bundle?

Also am I right that core means actually two things?

- the core library in /Component
- the whole setup with caching of routes/config/templates, admin interface, ...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Symfony2 framework is made of: Components, Bridges, and Bundles.

A Component is a standalone library which can be used independently.

A Bridge is a set of classes from one component that extends another library/component. It has been created so components can stay as decoupled as possible. This is also here for a good reason: If you want to use the Form component but do not use Doctrine as an ORM, you don't care about the specific Type created for Doctrine.

A Bundle is a glue between components or Third-Party libraries. The glue of all these components and bridges that make the Symfony2 framework is the FrameworkBundle.

Then, you have the distributions. A distribution is a set of Bundles, third-party libraries and default configurations that makes the installation of Symfony2 really easy for a project.

Comment: +1 great explanation, this should be in the Symfony2 docs (unless it is and I missed it ;) )

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by glue as a metaphor for "bundle" ... to me this sounds like it's basically a bridge! but if I understand you correctly then the existance of a bridge for 3rd-party-component does not create a dependency for this component. It is just used if necessary. !?

Comment: Bridges extend functionalities of Components. Bundles extend functionalities of the Framework or the Application.