# Symfony2 Inheritance Working

Tags: inheritance, symfony, bundle

I want to use Symfony2 Bundle inheritance feature for overriding its core translation component. Before I proceed want to have some advice over it. Is it possible to do?

Comment: Have you tried http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html ?

Comment: Yes I tried. Perhaps also tried to inherit a vendor bundle. I found it bit complicated and appears that things not work as described in documentation. Also in first paragraph of documentation it says that "Symfony gives you a very convenient way to override things like controllers, templates, and other files in a bundle's Resources/ directory". I think it means only from Resources/ folder. Although I invested about 7 hrs since morning to inherit vendor bundle found no success. So that is why I asked this question. Since translator is core component.

Answer (score 2):

Symfony2 has an easy way to override **bundles**, but you want to override the Translation **Component** (more information about the differences between bundles, components and bridge in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7122099/1149495)).

If you want to override the Translation Component, you can take the advantages of Dependency Injection. If the Symfony2 framework uses the translation, it uses one of the translation services. So if you need to override whatever you want, edit a Translation service. You can find all translation services and parameters in `vendor/symfony/src/symfony/bundle/frameworkbundle/resources/config/translation.xml`.

You can see that Symfony stores every class they used as a service as a parameter, you need to just change the parameter to the class name you want and you are ready!

For instance, we want to override the `Translator`. We can generate a `Acme\DemoBundle\Translation\Translator` class that extends at least `Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface` and add this to our service configuration:

```
parameters:
    translator.class: Acme\Demobundle\Translation\Translator
```

Comment: Hi Wouter, I tried to implement it. I followed steps as stated here. But got no success. translator.class: Acme\Demobundle\Translation\Translator, this has to be set in translation.xml or where? In my try I set it in translation.xml. Please clarify.

Comment: @bharatesh You define the parameters in your `app/config/config.yml` file (or define it in your bundle and use an extension: [the docs about this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html)). I have used the Yaml format here, if you want PHP or XML just say it and I will include those too. Maybe it is a good idea to learn more about Symfony2 and DI in [the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html)